# Adding Data to column based on content of other cells (Python/Excel)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

everybody,

I'm trying to automate the allocation of inventory. Since I am not an experienced programmer, I have difficulties in creating the logic.

The goal is to combine two Excel files and add a column containing the responsible persons/departments. What I have managed so far is to combine the Excel files and add the column "Reviser". Now this column must be filled with the right persons/departments.

The logic behind this is not very difficult, but I don't really know how to do this with Python/Pandas etc.
I already tried to fix this problem with np.where but that doesn´t fix the problem completely.

Here you can see the logic behind the assignment of the revisor:

[Logic behind assignment][1]

Thanks for your help!

My current code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from openpyxl import Workbook

Q_Stock = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Desktop\\Excel_Test\\Q Bestand.xlsx",usecols=["Bestandsqualifikation", "Inhalt", "Benutzerfeld 1", "Benutzerfeld 2","Material", "Externer Barcode 2", "Handling Unit"])
""" Q_Bestand["Bearbeiter"] = "" """
Q_Stocknew = Q_Stock[0:-1]

S_Stock = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Desktop\\Excel_Test\\S Bestand.xlsx",usecols=["Bestandsqualifikation", "Inhalt", "Benutzerfeld 1", "Benutzerfeld 2","Material", "Externer Barcode 2", "Handling Unit" ])
""" S_Bestand["Bearbeiter"] = "" """
S_Stocknew = S_Stock[0:-1]


complete_list = [S_Stocknew, Q_Stocknew]

Combined = pd.concat(complete_list)
df = pd.DataFrame
def bar(df):
    if Combined['Inhalt'] ==np.nan:
        return np.nan
    elif str(Combined['Inhalt']).contains("QV"):
        return "Distribution"
    elif str(Combined['Inhalt']).contains("QP"):
        return "Production"
    elif (Combined['Benutzerfeld 2'] == "ruckschnitt") and (str(Combined['Material']).contains("^09")):
        return "Person 1"
df["Reviser"] = Combined.apply(bar, axis = 1)





Combined.to_excel(r'C:\\Users\Lucas\\Desktop\\Excel_Test\\Test.xlsx', index = True)
```

Which throws out this error now:

C:\Python\Code\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Python/Code/SAP_Automatisieren.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python/Code/SAP_Automatisieren.py", line 29, in 
    df["Reviser"] = Combined.apply(bar, axis = 1)
  File "C:\Python\Code\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 6878, in apply
    return op.get_result()
  File "C:\Python\Code\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 186, in get_result
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "C:\Python\Code\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 295, in apply_standard
    result = libreduction.compute_reduction(
  File "pandas_libs\reduction.pyx", line 620, in pandas._libs.reduction.compute_reduction
  File "pandas_libs\reduction.pyx", line 128, in pandas._libs.reduction.Reducer.get_result
  File "C:/Python/Code/SAP_Automatisieren.py", line 19, in bar
    if Combined['Inhalt'] ==np.nan:
  File "C:\Python\Code\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1478, in **nonzero**
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from openpyxl import Workbook

Q_Stock = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Desktop\\Excel_Test\\Q Bestand.xlsx",usecols=["Bestandsqualifikation", "Inhalt", "Benutzerfeld 1", "Benutzerfeld 2","Material", "Externer Barcode 2", "Handling Unit"])
""" Q_Bestand["Bearbeiter"] = "" """
Q_Stocknew = Q_Stock[0:-1]

S_Stock = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Desktop\\Excel_Test\\S Bestand.xlsx",usecols=["Bestandsqualifikation", "Inhalt", "Benutzerfeld 1", "Benutzerfeld 2","Material", "Externer Barcode 2", "Handling Unit" ])
""" S_Bestand["Bearbeiter"] = "" """
S_Stocknew = S_Stock[0:-1]


complete_list = [S_Stocknew, Q_Stocknew]

Combined = pd.concat(complete_list)
df = pd.DataFrame
def bar(Combined):
    if Combined['Inhalt'] ==np.nan:
        return np.nan
    elif str(Combined['Inhalt']).contains("QV"):
        return "Distribution"
    elif str(Combined['Inhalt']).contains("QP"):
        return "Production"
    elif (Combined['Benutzerfeld 2'] == "ruckschnitt") and (str(Combined['Material']).contains("^09")):
        return "Person 1"

df["Reviser"] = Combined.apply(bar, axis = 1)
```

Error:

C:\Python\Code\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Python/Code/SAP_Automatisieren.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python/Code/SAP_Automatisieren.py", line 28, in 
    df["Reviser"] = Combined.apply(bar, axis = 1)
  File "C:\Python\Code\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 6878, in apply
    return op.get_result()
  File "C:\Python\Code\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 186, in get_result
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "C:\Python\Code\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 295, in apply_standard
    result = libreduction.compute_reduction(
  File "pandas_libs\reduction.pyx", line 620, in pandas._libs.reduction.compute_reduction
  File "pandas_libs\reduction.pyx", line 128, in pandas._libs.reduction.Reducer.get_result
  File "C:/Python/Code/SAP_Automatisieren.py", line 21, in bar
    elif str(Combined['Inhalt']).contains("QV"):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function like below and apply this to your dataframe. You can also write a nested `np.where` but below function will be more readable for you coming from Excel world

```
def bar(df):
    if df['Inventory Qualifikation'] ==np.nan:
        return np.nan
    elif str(df['Inventory Qualifikation']).contains("QV"):
        return "Distribution"
    elif str(df['Inventory Qualifikation']).contains("QP"):
        return "Production"
    elif (df['Userfield 2'] == "ruckschnitt") and (str(df['material']).contains("^09")):
    return "Person 1"

df['reviser'] = df.apply(bar, axis = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But i still get some errors. So "def" = saying I wanna define a function, bar = name of function, (df) = dataframe I want the function to be alligned to? I added my new code..

Comment: what is the error you are getting? can you copy paste the error here?

Comment: Yes I added it below the new code. It´s too long for the comment section..

Comment: I edited the answer now. Can you try the edited version.. Please note i change `df[].str to str(df[])`

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I think I miss something: functions in python start with "def" then comes the name "bar". Which dataframe is in the bracket behind "bar"? The dataframe within the function like "if df["inventory qualification"] is the dataframe where the column "inventory qualification" is contained. (In my case: complete_list?). Then there is the last dataframe outside of the function "df["reviser"] =..." This will give me a new dataframe with the column "reviser", right? And I have to apply it to my already existing  complete_list df?

Comment: Yes, you need a dataframe with all the columns that you see inside the function. Let's say your dataframe is called df then you can apply the function to the dataframe like the way i showed in the answer

Comment: Yes okay.You can see it in the code: I combined two excel sheets with the columns: ["Bestandsqualifikation", "Inhalt", "Benutzerfeld 1", "Benutzerfeld 2","Material", "Externer Barcode 2", "Handling Unit" ] (sorry for german) I combined the two files within the "combined" dataframe. I am still not sure if I did this correctly. I created an empty dataframe called df which I use for the def bar (df) and df ["Reviser]... I will upload my whole code again. I still get an error

Comment: What did you get when you called `bar(Combined)`

Comment: Can you only run part of the funciton... `def bar(df):`
    `if df['Inventory Qualifikation'] ==np.nan:`
       ` return np.nan`
    `elif str(df['Inventory Qualifikation']).contains("QV"):`
    `return "Distribution"`

Comment: When I use def bar (df): it prints this error: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). And when I use def bar (Combined) it prints this error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'

Comment: I created a new dataframe with:                                                                               new_df = Combined[Combined["Inhalt"].str.contains("QV", na = False)]. I can print that out without any error

Comment: You are using the old script, i updated the script few days back. Please change your above script to `new_df = Combined[str(Combined["Inhalt"]).contains("QV", na = False)]` and see if you still get the same error